# Build Error in Android Studio Preview 4.1 Canary 10

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

I am trying to work on an application using Android Studio 4.1 Canary 10 but every time it throws build failed. Following is the error.

Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

> Could not get file details of E:\example\exampleapp\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug: could not file attributes (errno 87)

build.gradle file

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.exampleapp"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}

}

dependencies {

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev09'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev09'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev09'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev09'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

classpath dependencies :

```
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-alpha10"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I did clean and rebuild the project it didn't help. Any help would be great

Thank you

Comment: Android 4.0 is now released on stable channel . You should upgrade and try again

Comment: Am talking about studio preview @xaif

Comment: replace $kotlin_version  with actual version

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't to reproduce topic issue. And due to newbie reputation score ­— comment-section read only for my account now. So I post the answer. Avoid blaming me if it possible, please.

Try to add to application `build.gradle` file following:

```
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.3.70-dev-withExperimentalGoogleExtensions-20200424"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "0.1.0-dev09"
    }
```

just before `buildTypes { … }` block.